# Current Bandwidth (Hz) parameter

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

My BLDC motor has an on board controller which has torque, position and velocity tracking capabilities (see image below). One of the adjustable parameters, `Current Bandwidth (Hz)` can be set between the range of 0Hz to 1000Hz. I'd like to know if this value represents the rate at which the controller operates? If so, would increasing this value too high (~950Hz) potentially cause the motor to chatter (vibrate) when high Kp and Kd gains are selected? On the other hand, should the value be set too low (~20Hz) - it would have a long settling time?

[image]

Comment: Please link the data sheet / manual for the controller.

Comment: There are two manuals from the website (https://store.tmotor.com/goods.php?id=1030):  https://store.cubemars.com/images/file/20211201/1638329381542610.pdf
and http://store.tmotor.com/images/file/20210428/1619594329348464.pdf. However, the parameter is not mentioned in either but rather in the motor parameter setup menu (similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzY9vzgPZkA at time 2.44)

Comment: Where is the motor parameter setup menu?

Comment: It gets displayed once the motor is connected to the computer - it is the same menu as the one shown in the above video link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzY9vzgPZkA at time 2.44)

Comment: Sorry, but if the only place the feature is documented is in a video, I would say it is unreliable enough to make a proper decent answer out of it.